# ASP.Net custom error page not shown on iPad/Android

Tags: android, asp.net, ipad, mobile-safari, android-browser

In an ASP.Net app I have a custom error page configured.  It provides a fault reference so the user can follow up with support if desired, a link to log out and the application menu so that they can try something else.  The page sets the `Response.StatusCode` to `500`, because the nature of the error handling is that this page will also get used for errors in AJAX requests and so on and for those I want correct HTTP semantics.  But it still gets displayed on all the major desktop browsers.

However on the iPad and a test Android tablet the browser is displaying its own error page with none of this useful information or options on it.

If I change the response status code to 200 the custom error page is shown on both devices, but this change will cause problems elsewhere in the app (with AJAX requests) and, besides, doesn't feel right to me.  Is there anyway I can force the iPad/Android device to display my custom error page instead of it's own built in one?